# MVC 4.0 assign model property to jQuery variable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Please assist here if its possible or suggest me the other way

C# code is as

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
        var newCircuit = new CircuitViewModel();
        newCircuit.Workouts = _db.Workouts.ToList();
        newCircuit.MemberId = _memberId;
        return View(newCircuit);
}
```

on cshtml page code is as

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlWorkout", new SelectList(Model.Workouts, "Id", "Name"), "--Select Workout--", new { required = true, style = "width:310px", onchange = "GetExercise(this)" })
```

jQuery code is as:

```
function GetExercise() {     
    var Workouts = @Model.Workouts
    var AllExercises = Workouts[0].Exercises; 
}
```

Basically in model I have workouts and under each workout there are multiple exercises, so when I select workout I want to show all exercises and If I choose another workout then so its relevant exercises, so on...

So basically I want to set `@Model.Workouts` in jQuery Workouts variable. But above jQuery code is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per your example use this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlWorkout", new SelectList(Model.Workouts, "Id", "Name"), "--Select Workout--", new { required = true, style = "width:310px", onchange = "GetExercise($(this))" })

function GetExercise($(this)) {     
var Workouts = $(this.val())
var AllExercises = Workouts[0].Exercises; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From above what i came to know is that you want the Id of Workout dropdown in Js, so that you can bind Exercise result based on Workout Id.
Do like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlWorkout", new SelectList(Model.Workouts, "Id", "Name"), "--Select Workout--", new { required = true, style = "width:310px", onchange = "GetExercise(this)" })
function GetExercise(obj) {     
    // First i'm checking whether user has selected any value in dropdown or not
    if(obj!="" || obj.val()>0)
    {
        var Workouts = obj.val(); //Will have dropdown value
        var AllExercises = Workouts[0].Exercises; //This line i did not get
    } 
}
```

Or else do like this

```
//Set id from dropdown
@Html.DropDownList("ddlWorkout", new SelectList(Model.Workouts, "Id", "Name"), "--Select Workout--", new { required = true, style = "width:310px", @id= "ddlWorkout" })

$(function() {   
    $("#ddlWorkout").change(function() {
         var obj = $("#ddlWorkout").val();
        // First i'm checking whether user has selected any value in dropdown or not
        if(obj != "" || obj>0)
        {
            var Workouts = obj.val(); //Will have dropdown value
           var AllExercises = //Pass Exercise id to get result here
    } 
}
```